# Query to project fields in mongodb till sum = n

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is a sample collection result sorted by an attribute.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d96f8245e1ffa18e26dd2e2"),
    "name" : "A",
    "discount" : 10
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d96f8245e1ffa18e26dd2e2"),
    "name" : "B",
    "discount" : 15
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d96f8245e1ffa18e26dd2e2"),
    "name" : "C",
    "discount" : 20
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d96f8245e1ffa18e26dd2e2"),
    "name" : "D",
    "discount" : 30
} .
```

Want to write a query which will project the docs where **sum(discount) < n**

Ex: find all docs till sum(discount) = 25 .

This should return first 2 docs .
Output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d96f8245e1ffa18e26dd2e2"),
        "name" : "A",
        "discount" : 10
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d96f8245e1ffa18e26dd2e2"),
        "name" : "B",
        "discount" : 15
    }
```

find all docs till sum(discount) = 45 .

This should return first 3 docs .

Comment: a "name" can have multiple discount entries, and they should be summed up?

Comment: 1 doc will have 1 name and 1 discount

Comment: That really should not be a database query. This is the sort of thing that causes feature bloat in various RDBMS products. What you want is simply achieved by iterating items of a cursor and closing the cursor once your "running total" has been achieved. In short, it's a "client code" problem instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn I was checking if we could do such thing through queries..Anyways I will pymongo to achieve the same.

Comment: So MongoDB cannot. Someone very unwise might suggest something with `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT" } }` as part of it, which is essentially putting your entire collection into a single document as an array. Whilst this *may work* for trivial datasets (such as in your question) this is not practical for real world usage. Iterate a cursor instead, since that is what they are for. If your data was actually small enough for horrible hacks to work, then you don't really even need a database.